# How to send mail from an OpenWrt router

Tags: linux, email, openwrt

I am using OpenWrt 10.03 and need to send "reports" from my router by email.
I have installed sendmail:

```
# opkg install mini-sendmail
```

Then I used my ISP's smtp server:

```
# echo -e "From: TEST@TEST.TES\nSubject: SUBJECT\nReply-to: TEST@TEST.TES\n\nBODYHERE" \
> | mini_sendmail -sMYISPSSMTPSERVER MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM
mini_sendmail: unexpected response 550 to RCPT TO command
```

Questions:

1. How could I know, that my ISP's blocking port 25?

   ```
   # telnet MYISPSSMTPSERVER 25
   220 MYISPSSMTPSERVER ESMTP ready
   quit
   221 MYISPSSMTPSERVER closing connection
   Connection closed by foreign host
   ```

   so it's not blocked?
2. If port 25 isn't blocked, then how could I check this? Do I need an "email user" at my ISP?
3. If I can't get email working, than I have to register a free e-mail address [gmail?], and find out, how to send e-mail [with username and password required] in OpenWRT
   The only problem is that, I don't want to store passwords on the router.

Comment: My be useful: list of smtp clients https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/email/smtp.client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: I installed ssmtp + registered a free email address with ssl smtp as follows:

```
# opkg install ssmtp

$ cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM
mailhub=SMTP.EXAMPLE.COM:465
rewriteDomain=EXAMPLE.COM
hostname=EXAMPLE.COM
FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
AuthUser=MYEMAIL
AuthPass=PASSWORDHERE

$ echo -e "From: MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM\nSubject: SUBJECT\nReply-to: MYEMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM\n\nBODYHERE" \
> | ssmtp -vvv MYOTHEREMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: openwrt has issues with ssl certificates (unless configured), I think msmtp is easier to configure with tls_certcheck off and can support attachments.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but it's one of the links that come up when searching "openwrt smtp"

Follow this link-
https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=18669

For sake of preventing linkrot issues..
First install.

```
# opkg install msmtp
```

Then create config file.

```
# cat /etc/msmtprc
account default

host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user account@gmail.com
password password

auto_from off
from account@gmail.com

tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck off

logfile
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

To email, use the usual sendmail approach.

Answer (score 1):

Can you take the router out of the equation and just send an email through telnet?  ISPs will often block outbound SMTP (tcp/25) altogether while permitting connections to their mail server, which you can use as a smarthost (that might require authentication) to relay mail for you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally consumer Internet service providers will block TCP/25 for all SMTP servers other than their own. So it would be perfectly normal to be able to telnet to it from your router.

Your ISP may require authentication before sending over SMTP and I do not believe mini_sendmail supports SMTP AUTH. You might look at ssmtp opkg instead of (or in addition to) mini_sendmail:
http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf